# How can we use TailwindCSS to proportionally scale an image to always fit within the viewport?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

We would like to use TailwindCSS to proportionally scale an image (i.e. without altering the aspect ratio) such that the image is fully visible "above the fold", horizontally and vertically centered, and has a configurable amount of padding between the image and sides of the window.

For example, say we have some code which looks like this ([Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/1n0Zu4cQ9s)):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" />

<html lang="en" class="min-h-screen bg-gray-50">
  <body class="min-h-screen">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <div class="flex min-h-screen sm:px-12 py-8">
        <img class="h-auto max-w-full drop-shadow-md sm:rounded-md" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x2500" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here the image needs to be resized such that its height is not larger than the available screen. Additionally there should be padding between the image and sides of the screen. (The `sm` breakpoint can be ignored; this is more important for larger screens.)

Ideally this will be achieved using only CSS (Tailwind specifically), however if necessary JavaScript is an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.h-screen` on the parent to your `img`. Then on your image use `.object-scale-down` with `max-h-full` and `m-auto`.

[Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/sXojL920u4).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" />

<html lang="en" class="bg-gray-50">

<body>
  <div class="flex justify-center sm:px-12 p-8 h-screen">
    <img class="object-scale-down max-h-full drop-shadow-md rounded-md m-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x2500" alt="" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will this is what you are looking for.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" />

<html lang="en" class="min-h-screen bg-gray-50">
  <body class="min-h-screen">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <div class="flex min-h-screen h-screen">
        <img class="h-auto object-contain max-w-full drop-shadow-md rounded-md" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x2500" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to scaling your images and keep their aspect ratio locked to a fixed size is by creating a "box" as the wrapper of the image and define its position as relative to an image that will be absolutely positioned within the box. So you are defining the size of the image by the size of the div and the size of the image will be contained within certain hacks that you set on the div box.

The trick consists in setting a padding value based on a percentage. That percentage will always have the width of the element "fixed".

1. Go to the tailwind.config.js file, below the theme, extend create, if you haven't, a spacing object, here you can copy mine:

```
            spacing: {
                '1/3': '33.33333%',
                '2/3': '66.66667%',
                '1/6': '16.666667%',
                '2/6': '33.333333%',
                '4/6': '66.666667%',
                '5/6': '83.333333%',
                '1/12': '8.333333%',
                '2/12': '16.666667%',
                '4/12': '33.333333%',
                '5/12': '41.666667%',
                '7/12': '58.333333%',
                '8/12': '66.666667%',
                '10/12': '83.333333%',
                '11/12': '91.666667%',
            },
```

Those are all customs but Tailwind already comes with percentage values, https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width, these are the "w-2/4" for example.

Selecting the number will be depending on the type of outcome you want, so if you're looking for taller or wider just pick the one that you need.

2. Next create the div, you'll always have a wrapper for the image, the wrapper should be defined "relative" to the image, and the image "absolute" to its wrapper parent so it sits on top of it claiming the "box" size.
3. Now place the image inside the perimeters of the new box by using whatever you need for the most part I've used " inset-0 h-full w-full"
4. Now "squash" the box and give the div these classes "h-0 object-cover object-top"

So in the end the wrapper and image elements should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" />
<html lang="en" class="min-h-screen bg-gray-50">
  <body class="min-h-screen">
<div class="relative h-0 pb-2/3 sm:pt-1/3 lg:pb-1/3">
    <img class="absolute w-full h-full inset-0 object-cover object-top"
        src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200" alt="metal post thumbnail"
    >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now your image should contain its aspect ratio no matter the size of the window, custom breakpoint, etc. The image will always be fixed to the aspect ratio set.